# Creating a nested dictionary python

Tags: python

Probably an example will be easier to explain this.

So imagine i have something  like this:

```
 word_dict = {"word": frequency}
```

example would I loop thru a paragraph and in that paragraph I found the word freq as

```
 word_dict = {"this":2,"that":4} # assume that all the cases have just these two words..
```

yepp its a strange dict..

Now, each paragraph is assigned to a story and this story has an id:

lets say i get this:

```
{1234: {word_dict}} # where 1234 is the story id
```

and then this story is contanined in a book:
So if do something like `book_dict[book_id][story_id]`, this would return me word_dict.

But there is a good chance that a same book_id, story_id will have different word_dict

i Know it sounds weird..

So what I want is that `book_dict[book_id][story_id] = [{word_dict}]` so it returns me a list of word dictionary..

How do I implement this.

Err. is the question making any sense?

Comment: as for your last question: not a lot ;) please separate code from text

Comment: Can you rephrase your question more clearly? What do you have in input, what do you want in output?

Comment: As a sidenote, you might look up the Counter object if you're looking up word frequencies: http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter (no need to reinvent the wheel when such a nice one is provided!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
book_dict = {}
for each book_id, story_id, word_dict in who_knows_what:
    if book_id not in book_dict:
        book_dict[book_id] = {}
    if story_id not in book_dict[book_id]:
        book_dict[book_id][story_id] = []
    book_dict[book_id][story_id].append( word_dict )
```

Comment: I stumbled on your answer and wonder if I could ask you to explain the 'each' keyword in the second line. I thought Python's  `for` was a `for each`. So, does the each refer to each member of the tuple?

Answer (score 3):

Another option is using [`setdefault`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
book_dict = {}
for each book_id, story_id, word_dict in who_knows_what:
    book_dict.setdefault(book_id, {}).setdefault(story_id, []).append(word_dict)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a shortened version of the answer by Scott Hunter:

```
book_dict = {}
for book_id, story_id, word_dict in who_knows_what:
    book_dict[book_id] = book_dict.get(book_id, {})
    book_dict[book_id][story_id] = book_dict[book_id].get(story_id, [])
    book_dict[book_id][story_id].append( word_dict )
```